# SQLAlchemy loads unrelated cached objects when using contains_eager

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm using the `contains_eager` functionality of SQLAlchemy and I'm seeing strange behavior when objects are already loaded in an existing session. Specifically, it seems that those objects are not filtered out of the relationship collection as they would be when loading data fresh.

Here is a minimal example. The steps are

1. Create a parent-child relationship.
2. Add a parent and two children with different `value`s.
3. Perform a joined, filtered query, using `contains_eager` to load matching children for the parent. Note that the `filter` should exclude one of the two children.
4. Observe that both children have been populated on the `children` property of the resulting object.
5. The correct results can be obtained by using a new session, or even by calling `session.expire_all()`, which indicates that the issue is that the children already exist in the current session.

Is this the expected behavior? And if so, is calling `expire_all` the right thing to do to avoid this?

More generally, should `contains_eager` be avoided because of this? It seems like a break in the abstraction if one has to keep track of whether or not a child object already exists before issuing a query. But maybe I am missing something.

```
from sqlalchemy import and_, Column, create_engine, DateTime, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import contains_eager, relationship, sessionmaker


create_statements = ["""
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS child;
    """, """
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS parent;
    """, """
    CREATE TABLE parent
    (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR
    );
    """, """
    CREATE TABLE child
    (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        parent_id INTEGER REFERENCES parent(id),
        value INTEGER
    );
    """
]

Base = declarative_base()


class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parent"
    __table_args__ = {'implicit_returning': False}
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    children = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent")


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "child"
    __table_args__ = {'implicit_returning': False}
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Parent.id))
    value = Column(Integer)

    parent = relationship(Parent, back_populates="children")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    engine = create_engine(f"sqlite:///")
    session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()

    for statement in create_statements:
        session.execute(statement)

    p1 = Parent(id=1, name="A")
    c1 = Child(id=1, parent=p1, value=10)
    c2 = Child(id=2, parent=p1, value=20)
    session.add_all([p1, c1, c2])
    session.flush()
    # session.expire_all()  # Uncommenting this makes the below work as expected.

    results = session \
        .query(Parent) \
        .join(Child, Parent.id == Child.parent_id) \
        .options(
            contains_eager(Parent.children)
        ).filter(Child.value < 15) \
        .order_by(Parent.id) \
        .all()

    print(len(results[0].children))  # We should only have 1 child.
    print(all(c.value < 15 for c in results[0].children))  # All children should match the above filter condition.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [asked this question](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5740) on the SQLAlchemy GitHub page. The solution is to use `populate_existing` on any query that uses `contains_eager` and `filter`. In my specific example, this query does the right thing

```
session \
        .query(Parent) \
        .join(Child, Parent.id == Child.parent_id) \
        .options(
            contains_eager(Parent.children)
        ).filter(Child.value < 15) \
        .order_by(Parent.id) \
        .populate_existing() \
        .all()
```